# How to set custom layout to item of menu?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

In my application i want use **popUp** menu with **icon** and i write below codes. 
But i want set my **custom layout** to `menu` **items**, but not show any item. 
**What I mean is**, Not show menu title and icon!

**My Java code :**

```
public void onMoreMenu(View view) {
    showPopupWindow(view);
}

void showPopupWindow(View view) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(AuctionDetailPage.this, view);
    try {
        Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper.getClass().getName());
                Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod("setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

**Menu code:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="none">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_2"
            android:title=""
            app:actionLayout="@layout/item_test"
            app:showAsAction="always" />

    </group>

</menu>
```

**Custom layout codes:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemNav_img"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:tint="#876"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemNav_txt"
        android:src="@drawable/about" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemNav_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#876"
        android:text="Test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix it and set my custom layout to menu items?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to have it as a popup menu or just want a custom layout on the default menu ?

Comment: @UmangBurman, i want set custom layout to menu and use this into popup menu. can you help me?

Comment: Yes, I've done something similar so.. Just a min..

Comment: @UmangBurman, thanks my bro. i will wait you and please help me. i really need your help. Thanks

Comment: Okay, What error are you getting?

Comment: @UmangBurman, no, not show me error! just not set RTL . show me icon left of title. i want show icon right of title

Comment: Can you paste your full java code please?

Comment: @UmangBurman, my full code is above. please help me :(

Comment: Full Activity code dude.. paste it

Comment: @UmangBurman, my full activity code is 1370lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so this can be done using ListPopupWindow(as per the docs) from the following steps:

Step1: Create a Model Class

```
public class Item {
    private String title;
    private int imageRes;

    public Item(String title, int imageRes) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imageRes = imageRes;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImageRes() {
        return imageRes;
    }

    public void setImageRes(int imageRes) {
        this.imageRes = imageRes;
    }
}
```

Step2: Create an Adapter

```
public class ListPopupWindowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    List<Item> mItemList;

    public ListPopupWindowAdapter(Context context, List<Item> itemList) {
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mItemList = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int i) {
        return mItemList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_menu, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvTitle.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
        holder.ivImage.setImageResource(getItem(position).getImageRes());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvTitle;
        ImageView ivImage;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            ivImage = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Step3: your_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemNav_img"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:tint="#876"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemNav_txt"
    android:src="@drawable/about" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemNav_txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="#876"
    android:text="Test" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, show `ListPopupWindow`

```
private void showListPopupWindow(View anchor) {
    final ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(this);

    List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.add(new Item("A", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    itemList.add(new Item("B", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    itemList.add(new Item("C", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    ListAdapter adapter = new ListPopupWindowAdapter(this, itemList);
    popupWindow.setAnchorView(anchor);
    popupWindow.setAdapter(adapter);
    popupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });
    popupWindow.show();
}
```

That's it, Try it and let me know.

Comment: thanks my dear bro for your helps. i use your code and show me popup menu with custom layout. but show items very tiny and not show title and image full text . why?

Comment: I think problem is `View anchor` . this menu width is menu image width !

Comment: can you help me my bro?

Comment: You need to define the width in the popupwindow object: popupWindow.width = ListPopupWindow.MATCH_PARENT or a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

Try these tutorials may be your problem get resolved.

https://stablekernel.com/using-custom-views-as-menu-items/

https://medium.com/@prakharsrivastava_219/creating-custom-menu-in-android-part-1-3-menu-design-b51a13a7d018

Answer (score 0):

```
void showPopupWindow(View view)
    {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseActivity(), view);
        try {
            Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName()))
                {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                    Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper.getClass().getName());
                    Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod("setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                    setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.job_menu, popup.getMenu());

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
        {

            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
            {
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.postNewJob) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseActivity(),CreateJobActivity.class);
                    getBaseActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (id == R.id.renewExpiredJob) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseActivity(),RenewExpireJobListActivity.class);
                    getBaseActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                if (id == R.id.viewMyJobs)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseActivity(), MyJobActivity.class);
                    getBaseActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;

            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
```

job_menu:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/postNewJob"
        android:title="Post New Job"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_add_black"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/renewExpiredJob"
        android:title="Renew Expired Job"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_expired_job"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/viewMyJobs"
        android:title="View my Job Posts"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_jobs_tab_black"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: hey dear did you read my text? i want set custom layout to menu. i can use popup menu